# Mounting spots for a rectangular shaped object on a wall for optimal weight distribution

Tags: gravity, weight

I want to mount a rectangular metal plate (45 cm height, 32 cm width, 0.5 cm thickness) to my wall. For that I plan to glue magnet plates to my wall.

A proper weight distribution on the mounting magnets is key for me to keep the strain on the glue and the risk of the whole thing falling of the wall to a minimum.

Now I am wondering, if there is some kind of formular to calculate the best X spots on a plate where it should mount to the wall for the optimal weight distribution.

To visualize my problem: With 3 mounting spots, I would do something like this. But how can I be sure that this is correct. And also how to find the correct solution for a variable number of spots?
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the wall on which the magnets are mounted vertical or has an angle with the vertical?

Comment: It is completly vertical without any angle.

Comment: The plate is steel and holds due to friction and magnetic attraction?

Comment: The plate is steel and yes, pure magnetic attraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For minimum strain in each piece of glue, the force applied on the magnet by the glue it is stuck to should be upward to counteract gravity (and *only* gravity, and not other forces due to the magnets pulling the plate in different directions, etc.). The weight $Mg$ of the plate should be equally distributed among the pieces of glue, so the force on each glue should be $Mg/3$.

In addition, the torque applied on plate/magnet (about the point of contact) by the piece of glue it is stuck to should be zero, to avoid unnecessary strain. Under these conditions, the torque on the plate about the center of mass, pointing away from the wall, is
$$\tau = \frac{1}{3}Mg(x_1+x_2+x_3), $$
where $x_i$ denotes the x (or lateral) coordinate of magnet $i$, where the center of mass has $x = 0$. This torque should be zero for rotational equilibrium, so
$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0. $$
In other words, the average position of the magnets should be along the vertical line passing through the center of mass. There is no unique solution, any distribution satisfying this condition should fit the bill.

However, for possible stability issues and to prevent the plate from moving when pressed on one side, you probably don't want the magnets to lie on a straight line. The idea is the same as the reason the legs of a three-legged stool don't touch the ground along the same straight line. For this reason, the distribution of the magnets in your figure would be suitable.

Edit:

Here are a few more details about where the last equation comes from. In order for a rigid body to remain stationary, the net force and torque (about any point) on it must be zero. Otherwise if would begin to translate or rotate in an accelerating fashion. The torque about a point due to a force $\vec{F}$ applied to the body at another point separated from it by the position vector $\vec{r}$ is formally given by
$$ \vec{\tau} = \vec{r}\times\vec{F}. $$
The torque has the magnitude
$$\tau = rF \sin\theta$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{F}$. The direction of the torque gives the sense of rotation, where in this case the torque on the plate points either into the wall (trying to rotate the plate clockwise) or out of the wall (counter-clockwise). We can define a "scalar torque" as the torque pointing out of the wall. In this case, because of the $\sin \theta$ factor, only the lateral distance to the center of mass will matter and the magnitude of this torque will be
$$ |\tau| = F|x| $$
where $x$ is the coordinate defined as before, and $F$ is the upward force. However, upward forces to the left of the center of mass cause an inward torque, and so must have a negative sign. The "scalar torque" has the correct sign if we write
$$ \tau = Fx $$
The sum all all torques must be zero, which gives the torque balance equation above.

Comment: Good answer!  Additionally, for stability, it's better to have the majority of the magnets at the top than at the bottom.  If they were all at then bottom and the plate is perturbed from the vertical, then the weight of the plate will add an extra force trying to "peel" the magnets off the wall.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your awesome answer!
Could you, by any chance, explain how you came to the formula you used? Is it a common formula in physics ?

Comment: Torque balance is a necessary condition to keep a rigid body stationary, see my updated answer for details.